# Is this question suitable for the site? "Did Gaza have the potential to become a 'Singapore' in the Middle East?"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope, off-topic, questions

I have seen claims by pro-Israeli commentators that, after Israel disengaged from Gaza in 2005, Gaza was no longer occupied and could have become a “Singapore” of the Middle East if the international aid they received was put to good use.

I would like to know if asking whether this claim is true (if Gaza had the potential to turn into a place with a high standard of living). Is this question suitable for the site? What details do I need to provide when asking? If not, is there any other place where it would be suitable?

Sample question:

> I have seen claims by pro-Israeli commentators that, after Israel disengaged from Gaza in 2005, Gaza was no longer occupied and could have become a “Singapore” of the Middle East if the international aid they received was put to good use (lifting people out of poverty, investing in the economy etc.). It seems the example of Singapore was chosen because it’s a small country with a relatively high [Human Development Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index).
>
> *[Link to some famous pro-Israel commentator claiming this]*
>
> *[Link to some credible source stating how much international aid Gaza has received]*
>
> Did Gaza indeed have the potential to become a place where people enjoy a relatively high standard of living on an international scale? Or were there budget, trade and/or other constraints that prevented the standard of living in Gaza to rise to such a level?
>
> The rationale behind this question is that the same commentators claim that most of the international aid was either pocketed by corrupt politicians, or used to build tunnels and develop weapons. So, answering this question will help understand where the international aid was actually spent (on improving people’s lives or was it misused).

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include what you would ask on the main site so better advice can be given if it is on topic or not.

Comment: @JoeW Thanks for the suggestion. I have added it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question I sometimes ask people who post questions is "What would you expect an answer might look like, for and against the proposition?"

I can't imagine what a "No" answer would look. How could you say "There is zero chance of it happening"? If you can't say there is zero chance, then presumably you have to accept there is *some* potential. This *appears* to be unfalsifiable.

The only possible Yes answer I can imagine is first trying to hunt down what the original claimants meant when they said "a Singapore", and then finding an suitable economist who expressed an opinion based on an alternative history - but it would only be an opinion. We have no way of providing empirical evidence to support the claim. So it still wouldn't be a good fit here.

Now, this answer is an [argument from personal incredulity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity): Just because *I* can't imagine a good answer doesn't mean there couldn't be one. So, it is logically weak - that's why I prefer to ask the OP whether they can imagine a good answer, rather than assuming they can't.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I imagine a "No" answer to be that the international aid is not enough compared to the size of the population, and/or that Gaza had other constraints that prevent people from having a good standard of living (e.g., inability to import and export freely)

Comment: Regarding the comparison with Singapore, yes it is vague but it seems they mean a place where people have a relatively high standard of living on an international scale.

Comment: I would assume that international aid is never going to be enough *alone* to give the country a high standard of living - because you would no longer meet the criteria for needing aid well before that happens. The country would need to grow its own industries; which is hard and requires a lot of luck... but the *potential* is there.

Comment: Is that what they are referring to by Singapore? Maybe. Singapore has a high quality of life for South East Asia, but on the global scale it isn't particularly special. I was wondering if they meant "Small nation with limited national resources and agriculture that nonetheless thrives on being a trade hub, finance and high-tech manufacturing." suggesting Gaza could somehow follow suit.

Comment: Seems Singapore is currently ranked #12 internationally for their Human Development Index (health, education, income, living conditions): https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index

Comment: Their points seems to be that Gaza could have invested the money from international aid to grow its industries and improve people's standard of living.

Comment: @hb20007 One unasked question is would people still be giving Gaza aid if they decided to invest it in industries instead of using it to help people in need? It should never be forgotten what the purpose of the aid that is given is and how people would react if it is used for other things.

Comment: @hb20007: My apologies to you and the people of Singapore. The [first site I looked at](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/standard-of-living-by-country) turns out to have a faulty sort algorithm, and puts Singapore much lower when you "sort" by HDI-UN.

Comment: @JoeW The people making this claim believe that the money was not used neither for helping people in need nor was it invested, but instead that it was mostly used for building tunnels, buying weapons or was pocketed by corrupt politicians. Either helping people in need or investing it would contribute to a higher standard or living.

Comment: @hb20007 I think that is a different question then what you asked

Comment: @JoeW I updated my sample question here to show how they are linked.